# Create Files with Different Character Encodings from Z-Shell

Tags: zsh, encoding

I'm trying to understand character encoding better. To experiment, I want to take a string of characters and encode in different ways. Does zsh prompt have a way to create files that use specific character encodings? For example, I'm trying to create files that use the following character encodings:

- ASCII
- Unicode
- UTF32
- UTF8

I'd like to see the same string of characters encoded in each of these encodings to compare and contrast them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *shell,* zsh mostly doesn't deal with such things directly – but you can do it by running other programs *through* zsh. (Although, sure, zsh in particular is very rich in built-in functions unlike most other shells, but character encoding conversion doesn't seem to be one of them.)

To convert character encodings within the shell, usually the `iconv` tool is used – the `-f` option specifies what encoding to convert from; `-t` the target encoding; and data is read from stdin. For example:

```
echo "Here are some arrows , , , " > text_in_utf8.txt

iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 < text_in_utf8.txt > text_in_utf16.txt
```

(Usually the system locale is set to UTF-8, so anything you type directly into the shell – e.g. the `echo` in the above example – will also end up being UTF-8. But make sure to check it using `locale charmap`.)

Other character encodings such as `iso8859-1` or `ibm437` are also available; see `iconv -l` for a list. (Note that "Unicode" is just the abstract character set but not an encoding in itself. When you see "Unicode" as an encoding in Windows, that actually means UTF-16, or UCS-2 in very old versions).

There are also other ways to experiment with character encodings. For example, in Python you can `.encode()` a Unicode string into bytes using a specific encoding, or `.decode()` bytes back to a Unicode string:

```
$ python
>>> text = "   "
>>> utf8bytes = text.encode("utf-8")
>>> utf16bytes = text.encode("utf-16")
>>> ["%02x" % b for b in utf8bytes]
['f0', '9f', 'a0', '88', '20', 'f0', '9f', 'a0', '8a', '20',
 'f0', '9f', 'a0', '89', '20', 'f0', '9f', 'a0', '8b']
```

*(In this case, I do mean "Unicode string" in the abstract sense, unlike the earlier note.)*

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm curious, what encoding would make the arrows you shared render? I just see boxes regardless of the encoding I use.

Comment: If you `cat` a file in a terminal, its encoding has to be the same as what's used by your terminal, i.e. usually UTF-8. But usually this is not the fault of the encoding, but of the fonts that you have installed. (And not all terminal emulators can use the full set of system fonts, for various reasons.)